# non isomorphic finite dimensional $C*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

How many non isomorphic finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras if the dimensions without a bound? Is it countable or uncountable?

Comment: Finite-dimensional C*-algebras are finite products of matrix algebras.

Comment: This would be a more interesting question for a fixed dimension $d$ (although completely unrelated to $C^\ast$-algebras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$, the set of (isomorphism classes) of $C^*$-algebras of dimension $\leq n$ is finite (being the number of collections $\{(n_1,m_1),\ldots,(n_k,m_k)\}$ of pairs of natural numbers with the $m_j$ distinct such that $n_1\cdot m_1^2+\cdots+n_k\cdot m_k^2\leq n$), hence the collection of (isomorphism classes) of finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras is countable.

Comment: why shuould we multiply $n_k$?each finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra is $*$ isomorphic to direct sum of matrix algebras

Comment: I meant to write that the $m_j$ were distinct.  This just allows for multiple $M_{m_j}(\mathbb C)$ summands in the same algebra.